# Understanding why some content is shown in a view and other isn't

Tags: android, textview, android-linearlayout

I'm using the android map utils to cluster the markers on my map. Besides that, I'm creating a custom infowindow. I've made two implementations of my infowindow layout.

In implementation A all content is properly displayed and, If I add any other `TextView` to one of my columns, the infowindow height is increased and the content is all shown.

In implementation B after the fifth row the content is not shown.

**If implementation A is displaying all content why do I do not keep implementation A?**

Simple. Because the `TextView` on the left is related with the `TextView` on the right so the tops of those `TextView` must be in the same "line".

**Implementation A**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="20sp"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    />

            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    />

            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    />

            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    />

            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    />

            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    />

            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                     />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    />

            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    />

            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    />

            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    />

            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    />

            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    />

            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    />

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Implementation B**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp">

        <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="20sp"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"/>

            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"/>

            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"/>

            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"/>

            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"/>

            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"/>

            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"/>

            <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0.5"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Can someone explain me what do I have to do so that all the content of implementation B is shown on my infowindow?

Answer (score 0):

Solution is straightforward: you should use a scrollable wrapper. In Android, view is not scrollable by default. That's why you cannot see your content. It is just "pushed at the bottom" of your layout.

Easiest solution is to use a `ScrollView`. Includes your main layout within it to make your whole view scrollable.

However, here, it seems you would like to display multiple elements and apply same layout to them. Then, you should glance at `ListView` and `GridView` components. Using them, you are able to display multiple elements one by one and use same design each time, thanks to adapters.

Keep in mind `ListView` and `GridView` have their own scroll system. You shall not use them with a `ScrollView`. Further, in Android, you shall not use two scrollable contents in the same view/layout.

**EDIT:**

Your `TextView` are not visible in B implementation for you set a wrong `layout_weight` value: use `1` instead of `0.5`.

You want your views to have the same weight, sharing available space. However, if you want one to use 75% of space and the other one only 25%, you must set their respective `layout_weight` to `0.75` and `0.25`.

Comment: Thanks but the problem isn't inserting a `ScrollView`. I want to understand why with implementation A all the textviews are shown and with implementation B they are not ll shown.

Comment: Thanks again but the problem is in the height. The left textview as the same weight as the right textview. So they make a line pair with the same weight. This works for the first lines. After a while, some lines are not shown.

Comment: Um that's strange. Have you checked there is content in them? You should use the Hierarchy Viewer tool in Android. It will help you investigating your current layout.
Also, your layout is very close to a table. You should glance at `TableLayout`, it might help you.